# Extracting the date from multiple file names, python

Tags: python, regex, sorting, date

I have a list of CSV file names that I am trying to get the date out of in order to put them into order by date

Heres a snippet of the file names

```
csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/02-01-2020.csv
csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-31-2020.csv
csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/02-02-2020.csv
csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-24-2020.csv
csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-29-2020.csv
```

I can get the date from a single file using

```
a_date_string= all_files[0].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
print(a_date_string)
```

which gives output

```
02-01-2020
```

How do I get the code to return all the dates? The code above was given I am just trying to manipulate it to be in order by the dates listed in the file name.

Comment: This is using python.

Comment: All dates in a list?. can't just add it into a loop?

Comment: Ive been told a for loop should work. Im new to programming so Im not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

```
dates = [i[-14:-4] for i in all_files]
print(dates)
```

See if this works for you. This would return a list of those dates.

If any doubts in this snippet let me know in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question regex, here is a possible solution:

`/(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\.csv$`

The resulting capture groups will contain the desired dates.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D0wpGd/6)

Comment: The regex tag was a recommendation. Im not even sure what it means.

Comment: @CollateralPigeon Let's get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2912665

Comment: Ill be looking into this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
a_date_string=[]
for file_name in all_files:
    a_date_string.append(file_name.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0])
print(a_date_string)
```

Assuming all_files is a list of all file names